# Selenium: Is there anyway to detect the Xpath easily of an element if Firebug is disabled?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I do have FireBug installed but it has the uncanny knack of disappearing mid-way during test prep. Then I have to use 'Inspect element(Q)" for finding out the element details.

Now, if I need to find the XPath of that element(for eg: a text entry box), how should I do it?

The XPath is listed but it's not shown in the simplified form as in FireBug. A pretty long path is seen and it becomes complicated to determine the exact XPath value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1)You can Use Selenium IDE(FireFox Add On), 
1. Open required web page on firefox.
2. Open Selenium IDE, Just record some actions.
3. Go to Target Field, Enter the XPATH in Target Feild and click on Find Button.

your required webelement will be highlighted in Yellow color.

Please find the attached Screenshot.[image: Screnshot 01]

2) Second Way to do this is, You can use XPath Checker Addons on Firefox, Once it is install just right click on the Element for which you have to identify the XPath, then select View X-PATH Option, You will get the x path with Namespace and XPath highlighted element.

Link for Addon : Xpath Checker : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/?src=ss
[image: XPATH Slection]

Comment: You can also add " https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/ " addon.

Answer (score 1):

Use below add-on. It will return you xpath

[Element Locator Add-On For Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/)

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Console

```
$x("xpathExpression") e.g $x("//input[@id='select_1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application opens up in chrome..then chrome too has capability to locate elements based on XPath..also have a look at FireFinder plugin too.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of depending on the xpath you can use the other properties as well for element identification.you can refer DOM for that.Or in worst case i think you can use different browser like chrome to find xpath or Internet Explorer.